# Inconsistent detection of beacons by raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, ibeacon

I am using raspberry pi for detecting beacons but many times I have observed there is inconsistent detection of beacons by raspberry pi.
Some of beacons are not getting detect by raspberry pi and some of getting detected once but after some time it not at all getting detecting.

I am using node **noble** (1.8.1) module for detecting beacons.

```
noble.on('discover', function(peripheral) {

  var id = peripheral.id;
  var entered = !inRange[id];

  if (entered) {
    inRange[id] = {
      peripheral: peripheral
    };
    var time = Date.now()-inRange[id].lastSeen;
    console.log(peripheral.id);

  inRange[id].lastSeen = Date.now();
});
```

I have searched regarding this but did't get any solution or resolution on it.

Comment: which raspberry pi model are you using?  are you using onboard Bluetooth or an external dongle?

Comment: I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B which consist of inbuilt bluetooth.

Comment: Is there any update regarding this issue ?